# Cassandra Not starting

Tags: java, windows, cassandra

I am using Windows 10 and I have installed Cassandra 3.9.0 and my updated JDK version is java version "1.8.0_211"

When I run the command `cassandra -f`
it stops giving me this error:

```
Exception (java.lang.AbstractMethodError) encountered during startup: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:145)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:219)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730)
ERROR 12:54:22 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$Exporter.exportObject(Ljava/rmi/Remote;ILjava/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory;Ljava/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory;Lsun/misc/ObjectInputFilter;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:150) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIJRMPServerImpl.export(RMIJRMPServerImpl.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:405) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils.createJMXServer(JMXServerUtils.java:106) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.maybeInitJmx(CassandraDaemon.java:145) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:219) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:730) [apache-cassandra-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
```

I have gone through many posts but none of them solves my problem. Please suggest. and let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 5):

see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173

> org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils which is used to
>   programatically configure the JMX server and RMI registry
>   (CASSANDRA-2967, CASSANDRA-10091) depends on some JDK internal
>   classes/interfaces. A change to one of these, introduced in Oracle JDK
>   1.8.0_162 is incompatible, which means we cannot build using that JDK version. Upgrading the JVM on a node running 3.6+ will result in
>   Cassandra being unable to start.

Upgrade to newer version of Cassandra (3.11.4 to date) or downgrade jdk first and the problem will be resolved